# Passing entire props to auxiliar functions triggers eslint prop-type errors

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

I have a simple stateless component like the one below (with more than one property, this is just for a demo):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

import MyDropdown from '...'

function renderDropdown (props) {
  return props.isOpened && <MyDropdown />
}

const MyComponent = function (props) {
  return (
    <div className='my-component'>
      {renderDropdown(props)}
    </div>
  )
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  isOpened: PropTypes.bool
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  isOpened: false
}

export default MyComponent
```

When I validate it with `estlint`, it throws many errors saying that there are properties missing in props validation, like this:

[image]

If I just pass the necessary properties or if I move the functions to inside the render it works perfectly.

Comment: Where are those errors pointing? Can you share that file?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an issue related to the following ESLint issues:

- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/237
- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1257
- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1422
- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1447

In that first issue, several people mention it could be caused by a simple typo, like using `PropTypes` instead of `propTypes`. I do see a typo in your code above (`MyComponent.propTyps`), but as it's sample code I doubt that's the issue.

Another potential issue mentioned in those is due to destructuring `this.props`, and the fix is to avoid destructuring of `this.props` using:

```
const props = this.props;
```

And instead going with one of these:

```
const {items, checked, onCheck} = this.props;
```

or selecting the properties using the longhand syntax:

```
this.props.items
```

or assigning `this.props` to a new variable:

```
const myProps = this.props
```

However, it also appears a fix has been proposed in https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/1605, so you might just need to wait and update ESLint when the fix has been pushed.

Comment: It seems like ```props``` is a reserved word that messes up the prop-types validation. The solution is simple, I've renamed the parameter of the ```renderDropdown``` function to anything else than ```props```.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the methods recommended in the issues. Sounds like a fix is on the way, so you'll need to update ESLint once it's available and then you can return to the standard naming convention.

Comment: Anyway, your answer helped me a lot, can you please add further information so I can accept it?

Comment: I mean, about the parameters called ```props```.